# Shouldn't array_udiff call my function for every iteration of my two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Running on php 7.3

Before someone asks, I have tested my compare function and it seems to work perfectly. If `compare($a, $b)` is 1 then `compare($b, $a)` is -1. If equal the inverse is still equal.The 'objects' below are all of the same class.

```
class myObject(){
    private $a;
    private $b;
    private $c;
    private $d;

    public function __construct($a, $b, $c, $d){
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
        $this->c = $c;
        $this->d = $d;
    }

    public static function compare(myObject $object_1, myObject $object_2){
         //This is somewhat complicated but my tests show that it works.
         return $result; // -1, 0. or 1
    }

    public function hasTwoNulls(){
        return $this->c === null && $this->d === null;
    }
}

$object_1 = new myObject('string', 'string', null, null);
$object_A = new myObject('string', 'string', null, null);
//etc....

$array_1 =[ $object_1, $object_2, //etc...];
$array_2 =[ $object_A, $object_B, //etc...];

$diff = array_udiff(
            $array_1,
            $array_2,
            static function( $a, $b ) {
                if($a->hasTwoNulls() && $b->hasTwoNulls()){
                    print 'I have a breakpoint on this line that is never reached!!!.';
                }
                return myObject::compare( $a, $b);  
            }
        );
```

As noted above, the breakpoint where I test for two nulls in each object is never reached even though it should be. I'm confused why it is never testing those objects together and why that object always ends up in my $diff even when I `myObject::compare( $a, $b);` those objects I get 0, aka equal.

It seems like it is doing some sort of comparisons without using my callback. Anyone have a read on this sorcery?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/7Ql0n Prints your message, not sure what else to say. (I had to fill in `$object_2` and `$object_B`, remove some comments, and overlook the compare function not working).

Comment: The breakpoint is only reached if the `if` test succeeds. Put the breakpoint before that to tell if the function is being called.

Comment: The code you have published has a number of minor syntax errors. I plugged it into PHPFiddle and fixed those, and it then works as I expect, including printing the breakpoint line.

Comment: @Barmar I've done that, and yes, it is being called but never are my objects with the 'twoNulls' called together.

Comment: @Scuzzy Very interesting it works there, like I would expect it to. In my project, with larger arrays, it does not call it on every iteration of my arrays.

Comment: Since this code doesn't exhibit the problem, can you provide some code and data that does?

Answer (score 2):

`array_udiff()` apparently has some optimizations to avoid comparing every pair of elements. I'm not sure of the exact algorithm, but I think it's sorting the two arrays and removing duplicates, and then stepping through them to find the matching elements.

You can see this with a much simpler example

```
$array1 = [1, 2, 3];
$array2 = [4, 5, 6];
var_dump(array_udiff($array1, $array2, function($a, $b) {
  echo "Comparing $a and $b<br>";
  if ($a < 4 && $b < 4) {
    return 0;
  } elseif ($a > 3 && $b > 3) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return rand(-1, 1);
  }
}));
```

Produces:

```
Comparing 1 and 2
Comparing 2 and 3
Comparing 4 and 5
Comparing 5 and 6
Comparing 1 and 4
Comparing 1 and 5
Comparing 1 and 6
Comparing 1 and 2
Comparing 2 and 3
array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) }
```

Comment: This is helpful. I'm not sure why but 2 is never directly compared to anything in $array2, neither is 3. This is replicating the issue I am having except it is also returning the correct answer, unlike my case. I wonder if there is some sort of undocumented expectations for the compare function. Perhaps in my situation the solution is to write my own diff function where I can at least know what is going on. It would be great to figure out what this undocumented behavior is actually doing.

Comment: Because my comparison function makes it think that all the elements of `$array1` are equal, so it only needs to compare with one of them. It assumes that the comparison function is transitive.

Comment: I missed that. I think I need to call it day here, brain = dead. I glossed over that bit assuming it was directly comparing. That makes sense on one hand but I wonder what conditions would take two objects that are equal and still have one show up in the diff.

Comment: Remember, the comparison function is not just equal/unequal, it's an ordering function. So it sorts the lists and compares elements in order.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware and my compare seems to behave just fine in my tests as mentioned in my question. There is certainly something strange a foot. I'm going to try another implementation of the needed functionality as see what happens.